# Is it possible to subset data using <2 boolean operators?

Tags: r, filter

I have a large dataframe, and I'm trying to run a `function` on subsetted rows, based on a few (more than 2) conditions. I'm trying to avoid creating hundreds of new dataframes by subsetting.

I've tried using the base `which` function, which I personally prefer (per now):

`function(data[which(apples == 1 & bananas == 2 & oranges == 3),])`

and using tidyverse pipetting:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  filter(apples == 1) %>%
  filter(bananas == 2) %>%
  filter(oranges == 3) %>%
  function(data)
```

Is there a way to make this possible?
(please excuse my bad examples, hope you get the idea)

Comment: You can group by and then apply a function in each subset. There are many ways to do it. Maybe it's better if you share  a realistic example and the desired output.

Comment: Your shown example will work also without `which`.

Comment: Maybe use data.table, e.g. data[apples == 1 & bananas == 2 & oranges == 3, newcolumn := value]

Comment: You can combine the `filter` statement into one : `data %>%
  filter(apples == 1, bananas == 2, oranges == 3)` . Not sure if this is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand what you want. But the only thing that I would add, is that you can connect your logical conditions in dplyr::filter(), the same way you did in which(), to avoid multiple filter's:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  filter(
   apples == 1 &
   bananas == 2 &
   oranges == 3
  ) %>%
  function(data)
```